# interface with base class and derived class to achieve multiple inheritance

Tags: c#

I got the following code where i would like to know the relationship between those class and interface.

Multiple inheritance wont work with C# but can we implement using interface?

Please tell me whether the following code will complie or not? why it is so ?
I am very confused?
Pleasehelp me out........

```
public interface MyInterface 
{ 
    void Method(); 
}

public class Base 
{
     public void Method() { }
}

public class Derived : Base, MyInterface { }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Please tell me whether the following code will complie or not?

Yes, it will - but you could have found that out for yourself just by trying it.

> Why it is so?

Quite simply, `Derived` implements the contract required by `MyInterface`. It happens to do that via `Base` which is unaware of the interface, but it still has all the relevant members.

There's a danger here, though - in reality, interfaces are about more than just having appropriate members available for callers; they're about the *semantics* of those members. A class hierarchy like this only works when the semantics of `Base.Method()` exactly match the requirements of `MyInterface.Method()` *by coincidence* (as opposed to by explicit, declared design). Even if it's valid to start with, the maintainer of `Base` may decide to make a change to the behaviour of `Method` which is valid according to what `Base.Method` has guaranteed, but *isn't* valid according to what the interface guarantees.

EDIT: In terms of the language specification, this is in section 13.4.4 of the C# 4 spec:

> A class or struct must provide implementations of all members of the interfaces that are listed in the base class list of the class or struct. The process of locating implementations of interface members in an implementing class or struct is known as interface mapping.
>
> Interface mapping for a class or struct C locates an implementation for each member of each interface specified in the base class list of C. The implementation of a particular interface member I.M, where I is the interface in which the member M is declared, is determined by examining each class or struct S, starting with C and repeating for each successive base class of C, until a match is located.
>
> [...]
>
> A compile-time error occurs if implementations cannot be located for all members of all interfaces specified in the base class list of C.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! I compiled and checked it already but i just want to know how those derived class works with the interface.

Comment: @VigneshLakshmanan: If you'd compiled it already, why did you explicitly ask whether it compiled? If you'd said: "This code compiles, but I don't understand why" that would have been a far more sensible question.

Comment: I am Sorry about that!!!!!!!! I had a doubt like why it is compiling and i am not sure of it why also? thats why i have asked question will it compile?

Comment: I am surprised the code has compiled. void Method() is not implemented in the Derived class.

Comment: @VigneshLakshmanan: But do you see that they're very different questions? "Does it compile?" is a question you could answer for yourself very easily, so asking it makes you look lazy - whereas "I've just tried this - it compiles, but I'm confused about why. Could someone explain?" doesn't imply laziness at all. It's important to be clear about what you know and what you don't when you ask a question.

Comment: @daryal: It doesn't have to be though - it's a public member of the `Derived` type, inherited from `Base`. I'll dig up the relevant bit of the language spec.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right I did not note that it is already in the base class, sorry to mislead, I thought there are two different signitures in the base class and the interface.

Comment: May be the way i have asked a question, would have been looked like 'I am a lazy' for you, but i dint ask the question in that mean, I have asked this question to know the answer. Next time onwards will make it correct.

Comment: @VigneshLakshmanan: My point is that that's probably why you've got 3 downvotes for your question, just in case you were wondering...